# Search by Max of Value in Eloquent Database Laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

How convert this Raw SQL to Eloquent Database in my API Controller?

What i'm tried is i wanna get data from Two Tables from My API Controller.

First: Formc_image Table which is general information about data

Second: Formc_image_detail which is detail and path of data

They are related by ID.

This is my API Controller FormCController.php

```
SELECT * 
FROM formc_image_detail
WHERE id_tps=$id_tps AND jenis_pemilihan=$election_id
AND versi = (SELECT MAX(versi) FROM formc_image WHERE id_tps=id_tps AND jenis_pemilihan=$election_id)
ORDER BY no_lembar ASC
```

This is my Model FormCImageDetail

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FormCImageDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'formc_image_detail';

    public function formc_image(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\FormCImage');
    }
}
```

This is my FormCImage Models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FormCImage extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'formc_image';
}
```

I was make this code in My API Controller:

```
return response(FormCImageDetail::with('formc_image')
      ->where('jenis_pemilihan', $electionId)
      ->where('id_tps', $tpsId)
      ->orderBy('no_lembar', 'ASC')->paginate(100)->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_OK);
```

But it still error.

This is my Migration:

```
Schema::create('formc_image', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id_tps');
            $table->smallint('versi');
            $table->string('jenis_pemilihan');
            $table->timestamps();
}

Schema::create('formc_image_detail', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id_tps');
            $table->smallint('versi');
            $table->integer('no_lembar');
            $table->string('jenis_pemilihan');
            $table->char('url_image', 100);
            $table->timestamps();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was updated my detail question. Please help me to solve this case @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```php
return FormCImageDetail::with('formc_image')
    ->where('jenis_pemilihan', $electionId)
    ->where('id_tps', $tpsId)
    ->where('versi', function($query) use($election_id) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('max(versi)'))
            ->from('formc_image')
            ->whereColumn('id_tps', 'formc_image_detail.id_tps')
            ->where('jenis_pemilihan', $election_id);
    })
    ->orderBy('no_lembar')
    ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But it still bug. Debug is local.ERROR: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string. @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: Still bug when i am run the code. Debug is local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column formc_image.id does not exist. @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: I just run your SQL solution in my API Controller @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: [2018-12-07 03:49:46] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column formc_image.id does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "formc_image" where "formc_image"."id" in ($1)
                                          ^ (SQL: select * from "formc_image" where "formc_image"."id" in ()) {"userId":6,"email":"davidwinalda94@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42703): SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column formc_image.id does not exist

Comment: LINE 1: select * from \"formc_image\" where \"formc_image\".\"id\" in ($1)
                                          ^ (SQL: select * from \"formc_image\" where \"formc_image\".\"id\" in ()) at C:\\xampp7\\htdocs\\situng-web\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 42703): SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column formc_image.id does not exist

Comment: Your `formc_image` relationship is incorrect. Please add the migrations of both tables to your question.

Comment: Use this: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\FormCImage', 'id_tps', 'id_tps');`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for helping me @JonasStaudenmeir